# Dangling else in python

Tags: python

Just want confirmation that this assertion is correct:

> python cannot ever experience the
>   dangling else problem

*UPDATE* fixed typo

Comment: Mh, double negation - it's either a trick question or a typo ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python's blocks are indentation-based, not delimiter-based, therefore it is possible to unambiguously associate an `else` clause with its corresponding primary clause.

Comment: hmm can u explain that a little more? Is there no way to create a dangling pointer in python? Not even with c modules?

Answer (score 0):

The dangling else is a problem in computer programming in which an optional `else` clause in an if-else statement results in a nested condition being ambiguous. Formally, the problem is with nested if, if there is only one else statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you're going to quote directly from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), you should cite your sources! :)